# Summary field values from some period

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In one table I have currency rate in some time period(five years). In another table, I have calculated data.
I have the task. I need to get statistics by every week summary  from joined tables
I am having this at the moment:

```
DECLARE @Category_RentHouse INT = 3;
DECLARE @Category_Parents INT = 5;
DECLARE @Category_Salary INT = 9;
DECLARE @TestDateStart DATE = '2012-01-01';
DECLARE @TestDateFinish DATE = '2012-01-07';
select Weeks, SUM(Cash_Usd) TotalMoney
from (select CAST(RateDate AS DATE) Weeks, 
       CASE  WHEN CategoryID = @Category_RentHouse THEN (TransactionAmount*(-1))
             WHEN CategoryID = @Category_Parents THEN TransactionAmount
             WHEN CategoryID = @Category_Salary THEN CAST((TransactionAmount / 
   RateValue) AS MONEY)
           ELSE CAST((TransactionAmount*(-1) / RateValue) AS MONEY)
END AS Cash_Usd
FROM (select * from Marathon.dbo.Transactions T 
LEFT JOIN IntermediateM.dbo.Rates R ON T.TransactionDate = R.RateDate) Y
    ) RR
WHERE Weeks BETWEEN @TestDateStart AND @TestDateFinish
GROUP BY DATEPART(week, Weeks), Weeks
ORDER BY Weeks
```

And result of run this small code is

[image: Result]

But it would better if in fields Weeks and TotalSumm I will get the next:

```
Weeks               TotalSumm
2012-01-07          -552...
2012-01-14          ....
```

Comment: please add a little sample data and the desired output

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to fix the `select` and `group by`:

```
SELECT MIN(Dte) as Weeks, SUM(Cash_Usd) TotalMoney
FROM (SELECT CAST(RateDate AS DATE) as Dte, 
             (CASE WHEN CategoryID = @Category_RentHouse THEN (TransactionAmount*(-1))
                   WHEN CategoryID = @Category_Parents THEN TransactionAmount
                   WHEN CategoryID = @Category_Salary THEN CAST((TransactionAmount / RateValue) AS MONEY)
                   ELSE CAST((TransactionAmount*(-1) / RateValue) AS MONEY)
              END) AS Cash_Usd
      FROM Marathon.dbo.Transactions T LEFT JOIN
           IntermediateM.dbo.Rates R
           ON T.TransactionDate = R.RateDate
      WHERE Weeks BETWEEN @TestDateStart AND @TestDateFinish
     ) RT
GROUP BY DATEPART(week, Weeks)
ORDER BY Weeks
```

Comment: You are right I had to fix it and I get the result. But unfortunately, I found that my query returns the result for only one year, not for five years.